# Remove background animation with XAML C#?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm creating a header with the back button and logo. I figured out how to add a background using

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Black">
[...]
</Grid>
```

But now I end up with the background being part of the page animation transition. What I want is exactly like the header background in Microsoft's Contoso News demonstration application on their "[Animating your UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452701.aspx#page_transition)" page. That first video shows all the content in the app being animated with the header being static.

I've tried multiple searches and putting together code I've thought would work, including messing with `<EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="0" FromVerticalOffset="0"/>`. Unless I'm missing something, I can't find documentation on removing an animation.

A step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the background on the page instead?

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Should I use Blend?

Comment: Find the top level element in your page and set the background on it.

Comment: I figured out how to adjust the animations. Typing up an answer right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I didn't read Microsoft's documentation thoroughly-enough during a 3am session.

What I needed to do was add a custom `EntranceThemeTransition` to the parent:

```
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="0" IsStaggeringEnabled="false"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `FromHorizontalOffset="0"` tells it to move zero pixels horizontally (in other words, not to animate at all), and `IsStaggeringEnabled="false"` tells it to render all the items at once. From here, I can add a custom animation to each of the children.

MSDN Resources:
[IsStaggeringEnabled property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition.isstaggeringenabled)
[FromHorizontalOffset property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition.fromhorizontaloffset)